# mail-listener2 in protractor does not fetch mails until marked seen/unseen in outlook

Tags: protractor, imap

i made a test with protractor and mail-listener2, which waits for an email (imap)
That worked long very well without problems - but now there is a strange effect:
Protractor does not get a mail. But it does, if I open outlook, fetch the mail there, mark it as seen and then unseen again. In the moment, I mark it unseen again, the mail-listener gets the email and Protrator can work with it.

I doubt whether I have changed any settings of the maillistener (i tried with an old version, too)
I think the maillistener uses "UNSEEN" as filter, if searchfilter is not set (if i read the imap.js code correctly). The mails are unseen if I open outlook.

The second strange effect: the receiving of mails works without any changes if there is a second case of receiving a mail within the same protractor-testsuite.

Does anyone has an idea, what might be wrong?

```js
 var mailListener = new MailListener({
      username: "webmaster@xxx.de",
      password: "xxx",
      host: "imap.strato.de",
      port: 993, // imap port 
      tls: true,
      tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
      mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor 
      markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time 
    });
```

Regards
Thomas

Comment: I solved the problem:
The problem accured obviously because I had changed my test. Before waiting for the mail I restarted the browser and had no longer an open app (i wanted to start again with the link in the mail)

When I changed the order to first get the mail, then logout and restart the browser and then click on the link, everything works fine again.

Comment: That's great! Can you post your solution as an answer please?

Comment: sorry: pressing return created the first answer post with 4 words only - I wanted a new line...
now the post is with solution :-)

Comment: maybe it was not the solution: I got the problem a second time. This one the solution was that i 'made to much' between sending the mail and receiving it. It seems that the mail-listener looks at the mails itself without beeing asked. Or I do not understand the concept due to poor documentation.

After moving the getmail-function further up, the mail was read. So I think I have to make improvement in my getmail-function to read all mails unseen or not. How do I get ALL mails instead of UNSEEN? Or should I start the mail-listener not in the On-prepare-area and in the test itself instead ?